# mysqli_rollback - увеличивает колличестов id можно этого избежать?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

mysqli_rollback($db) - увеличивает количество id при откатах. Можно этого избежать? что при откате id в базе оставался таким же как и до отката (не удавшейся транзакции)?

Comment: Это неправильно идеологически. Не трогай id. Это поле вообще не для тебя существует. Нужна непрерывная нумерация - заведи под эту цель ещё одно поле.

Comment: Обескуражен... Есть таблица - table.  В не поля : id, name, comment. Проводится транзакция с внесением записи в данную таблицу. При ошибки транзакции rollback осуществляет откат (убирает запись) , но счётчик id прибавил единицу. Это сбивает с толку. Можно ли от такого избавиться или ... в чём неправильный подход?

Comment: И чем сбивает с толку что id не по порядку?

Comment: Не используйте автоматическое сгенерированные номера, в чем проблем то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. auto_increment намеренно сделан не транзакционным и потому не откатывается при rollback. Так сделано специально для улучшения конкурентной обработки транзакций.

Ведь если бы последовательность откатывалась при rollback, это бы одновременно означало, что может одновременно выполняться только одна транзакция, пишущая в эту таблицу. Вторая транзакция бы не знала, какое значение ей можно использовать - следующее (если первая транзакция будет зафиксирована с commit) или то же самое что у первой транзакции (если та отменится). И поэтому при получении запроса insert в эту табличку начинала бы ждать окончание всей предшествующей очереди транзакций, желающих что-то записать в эту табличку.

---

Почему вас это беспокоит в целом? auto_increment даёт уникальное значение для этого поля. Всё. Больше ничего он не гарантирует. Ни неразрывности последовательности, ни, на самом деле, даже порядка - нет ничего неверного в том, если id = 5 будет записан раньше id = 3 при параллельной обработке транзакций.

auto_increment используется для суррогатного ключа, нет никакой разницы, какое значение он выдал.

Comment: *auto_increment даёт уникальное значение для этого поля. Всё. Больше ничего он не гарантирует.* Это немного не так. Он гарантирует, что любое сгенерированное значение больше любого ранее сгенерированного значения. Впрочем, между запросом на автоинкрементное значение и его фактическим присвоением может пройти достаточно времени, чтобы именно фактическое присвоение, в отличие от фактической генерации, выполнялось не по порядку.

Comment: а эта гарантия прописана где-то или просто следствие реализации? По диагонали глянул мануал, может пропустил.

Comment: Была мысль, чтоб во всех таблицах входящих в транзикцию было одно числовое значение id . Думал так будет лучше для проверки и поска. Наверное я ошибался.

Comment: @Мелкий *эта гарантия прописана где-то или просто следствие реализации?* Явно это нигде не прописано, это реализация. текущий автоинкремент - свойство таблицы. На время генерации по запросу соединения процедура генерации автоинкремента первым делом блокирует запись в системной таблице, и только потом читает, то есть конкурент по-любому вынужден ждать, чтобы даже прочитать текущее значение, и, когда запись будет освобождена, он получит уже обновлённое значение.